# how to handle DuplicateKeyException in Spring data mongodb

Tags: java, spring-mvc

**Method to insert data**

```
    public  String home()  {

    try
    {
    MongoData data=new MongoData();
    data.setDate(new Date());
    data.setName("frji");

    //mongoTemplate.insert(data);
    mongoTemplate.save(data);
    }
    catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {

    }
    catch (MongoException e) {

    }
    return "home";
}
```

**Entity class**

```
  @Document(collection="integer_test")
public class MongoData {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Date date;
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String name;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MongoData [date=" + date + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**But it does not catch the exception. it will show on user interface.Then how can i catch this exception in java end.**

> com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" :
>   "192.168.1.113:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "E11000 duplicate
>   key error index: jmailer_digiengage.integer_test.$name dup key: { :
>   \"frji\" }" , "code" : 11000}     at
>   com.mongodb.CommandResult.getWriteException(CommandResult.java:88)    at
>   com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:79)     at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.translateBulkWriteException(DBCollectionImpl.java:415)
>     at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertImpl(DBCollectionImpl.java:210)
>     at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:176)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:161)    at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:107)    at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:1214)     at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:1179)     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$11.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:479)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.saveDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:1101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1034)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:981)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:969)
>     at com.mongo.test.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:62)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: It lacks annotations on the Bean class. like `@Table`, `@Column`, `@Entity`. It's important for mapping with your database.

Comment: i am using mongodb databse so,don't need these annotation to communicate with db

Comment: this is working fine but i am trying to inserting duplicate name then it's generate DuplicateKeyException but i am not not handling at java end.

Comment: How can i handle this exception.

Comment: Catch `Exception` spring might be wrapping the mongo exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your **HandlerExceptionResolver** to handle and show the user friendly message to the UI.

[How to create HandlerExceptionResolver](https://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler-handlerexceptionresolver)

Update : If you just want to handle the exception then write `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException` in the catch block.

```
try{
  //TODO
} catch(org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException e){
 //TODO - Do what you want
}
```

Comment: Sorry I want to catch this exception and perform some other task within this method

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: i have used DuplicateKeyException of same package bt it is not work

Comment: Sorry this is my fault.i had imported com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException that's why it was not handling

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it does not catch the exception?  Your exception handling code doesn't do anything!

You need to add something meaningful to actually do something when a duplicate exception occur

```
public  String home()  {
  try {
    MongoData data=new MongoData();
    data.setDate(new Date());
    data.setName("frji");
    mongoTemplate.save(data);
  } catch (DuplicateKeyException | MongoException e) {
    //Exception handling
    return "an error occurred: " + e.getMessage();
  }
  return "home";
}
```

Or remove the exception handling, and let the exception be thrown.

```
public  String home()  {
  MongoData data=new MongoData();
  data.setDate(new Date());
  data.setName("frji");
  mongoTemplate.save(data);
  return "home";
}
```

Comment: i try to hit this method, if it generate DuplicateKeyException directly shows on user side.

Comment: i had tried, But exception occurred not go inside catch block

Comment: You will never get DuplicateKeyException in this catch block because in this clause, it is still Mongo exception. It is then propagated to the Spring and then the container produces DuplicateKeyException

Answer (score 0):

Answering quite late, but might help somebody.
Extending Mehraj Malik answer here,

another way is to catch exceptions and check inside if it is Duplicate or any other exception. In this way we can check for any other exception as well:

import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;

```
try {
// 
} catch(Exception ex) {
 log.info("Exception occurred: ", ex); //to log exception
  if(ex instanceof DuplicateKeyException) {
      // duplicate key exception exists
  } else {
  // do something else
  }

}
```